# Retrieve only one image with Html.ImageGetter?

Tags: android, html-parsing

Iv'e been using the ImageGetter() interface in the Html.fromHtml() to retrieve image urls from  a long html String. But since I only really need one image I don't want to go through the entire String and look for images. I would simply like to stop when I find the first image.

Any suggestions?

```
Html.fromHtml(html, new ImageGetter() {
    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        item.setImageUrl(source);
        return null;
    }
}, null);
```

EDIT : for now I only retrieve the last image in the html String so the ImageGetter will only retrieve that image.

private String getLastImage(String htmlContent){

```
    String img = "";
    try{
    img = htmlContent.substring(htmlContent.lastIndexOf("<img"));       
    }catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    return img;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a boolean field in your `ImageGetter`. In `getDrawable()`, fetch the image only if the boolean is `false` and then set it to `true`; return null otherwise.

To completely avoid parsing the rest of the HTML, you can not use `Html.fromHtml()`. Instead you may try using [`XMLPullParser`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html). Just keep pulling tags until you get an `<img>` tag, at which point get the value of its `<src>` attribute.

But you may have to handle inputs which are not strict XHTML properly.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I've tried that method and it works well for setting the image but the ImageGetter will still run through the entire Html String and look for images (even if it only will return null).

Comment: Okay that is one way to do it I guess but for now made a method to shorten the html String to only retrieve the last image part (if available).